# similar_text with large number of rows

Tags: algorithm, full-text-search

I'm currently using the similar_text function of PHP, I have a linkedlist with around 1000 nodes, each node has 5-200 chars.

What I'm doing now is going over each one of them and use similar_text and decide what to do next based on the percentage.

I'm sure this process is being affected after adding new node(s).

Is there any known method or algorithm I should follow better than the described above?

Comment: Is the linked list being sorted at all before this `similar_text()` process happens?  Also, what are some of the decisions included with the "decide what to do next based on the percentage" part?

Comment: No it's being not sorted, the decision is either ignore the text if the percentage is less than 80% or process it if above